# Windows Forms Update Dialogs/Sub Windows Dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

In a simulator I am writing I use SFML and OpenGL to create a visualization with some basic OpenGL based GUI. Now I need to add a File Chooser Dialog. I was wondering if I could use System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog and update it's events dynamically similarly to the way OpenCV allows you to update windows by using cv::waitkey().

Since OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() does not return until the window is dismissed, all I have to do is somehow close the Dialog by updating it's events.

I would rather not have to call Application.Run() and leave it in the background because my application is already built around a main loop and Application.Run() takes over the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent call to cv::waitkey is:

```
Application.DoEvents()
```

However after reading [Use of Application.DoEvents()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents) it appears that `Application.DoEvents()` is much more fragile then cv::waitkey. It can cause an application to crash if there is no open win form.

**Alternative Approach**

I decided to switch to GTK# since it lets you process events as they occur by checking whether any events exist in the event queue by calling `Gtk.Application.EventsPending()`. Then the events can be processed with `Gtk.Application.RunIteration()` in a while loop like this:

```
while (Gtk.Application.EventsPending())
{
    Gtk.Application.RunIteration();
}
```